# ERROR: mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Tags: php, mysql

Im very new to php and the mysql side of things and i was hoping someone could help me out, My code is returning the error:  mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result

Here is my code

```
$username = $_POST['username'];
$password = $_POST['password'];

if(isset($username) && isset($password)) {

    $connect = mysqli_connect("localhost","root","") or die("Couldnt connect!");

    mysqli_select_db($connect,"phplogin") or die("Couldnt find DB.");

    $query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username={$username}";
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($query);

    echo $numrows;
```

If someone could help me out and tell me what i done wrong and how i could echo out the number of rows i would glady appreciate it.

Comment: You're not actually running your query; you need to use `$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query)` to run it, and you can then call `mysqli_num_rows()` on $result.

Comment: The error message says "expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result". Does `$query` look remotely like a `mysqli_result`?

Comment: Use `var_dump($query);` that will tell you what's being passed through your query as well as `var_dump($numrows);`

Answer (score 0):

Function `mysqli_num_rows` expects result, you gave it `string`.

Before num_rows you have to call `$result = mysqli_query($db_connect, $query)`. Then you can count records using `mysqli_num_rows($result);`.

Answer (score 0):

You have to actually run the query first before you can see how many rows you have:

```
$query = "SELECT * FROM users WHERE username={$username}";

// Run the query
$result = mysqli_query($connect, $query);

$numrows = 0;

if(!$result)
{
    $numrows = mysqli_num_rows($result);
}
```

Remember to look up on the php.net website if you get stuck, it's a goldmine of help: http://www.php.net//manual/en/mysqli-result.num-rows.php

Comment: Hi ben, After doing what you commented it still returns a error mysqli_num_rows() expects parameter 1 to be mysqli_result, boolean given, Any suggestions?

Comment: I've updated, looks like your query returned an empty result set.

Comment: Nevermind, I found my problem, i was using WHERE username={$username}, it should have been WHERE username='$username' Thanks anyways for the help!